# Compile Assembly code that includes header files containing C-definitions

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, assembly, avr-gcc

I'm trying to compile assembly and C code together (not C to assembly), but can't get it done.

For example:

file common.h

```
#ifndef __COMMON_H__
#define __COMMON_H__

struct tree{
        tree* left;
        tree* right;

        void* elem;
};

void foo(int c);
#endif
```

file common.S

```
#include "common.h"

    .text
    .globl foo
    .ent foo
foo:
     //foo implementation

    .end foo
```

When I try to compile this:

```
# gcc -c common.S
common.h: Assembler messages:
common.h:5: Error: unrecognized opcode `struct tree{'
common.h:7: Error: unrecognized opcode `tree* left'
common.h:8: Error: unrecognized opcode `tree* right'
common.h:10: Error: unrecognized opcode `void* elem'
common.h:12: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `}'
common.h:14: Error: unrecognized opcode `void foo(int c)'
```

Is there any way to take C-definitions into assembly using gcc?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't include C declarations in assembly language.  The assembler has no idea what `struct tree` means.

If you want to write an assembly language function `foo` that makes use of your definition of `struct tree`, you're going to have to do it without making use of the C header file.

To get an idea of what this might look like, write the `foo` function in C, compile it with `gcc -S` to generate an assembly listing, and then take a look at the resulting compiler-generated `common.s` file.  (You should probably do this in a separate directory so you don't clobber your existing `common.s` file.)

You probably won't see any references to `struct tree` or to the member names `left`, `right`, and `elem`; instead, you'll see assembly opcodes that refer to data at certain offsets.

Answer (score 3):

The C preprocess is just text substitution / file inclusion, and `struct tree{ ... };` isn't valid GAS syntax.

---

If you have headers that have some `#define` constants useful for asm, you can put those parts inside `#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__`.

Or put the non-assembler-compatible parts in `#ifndef __ASSEMBLER__` blocks.

Or separate the asm-compatible parts into a `.h` file that asm can include.  The Linux kernel does this with a few things like `#include <asm/unistd.h>`.  (But there are other constants that don't have asm-friendly headers, so preprocessing them with `gcc -E -dM` to dump just the macro defines can be useful if you have some existing `.h` headers with mixes of `#define` macros and C syntax.)

---

When preprocessing a `.S` file, GCC pre-defines `__ASSEMBLER__` for you.  You could make up your own macro name yourself and have your Makefile use `gcc -DASM_ONLY` to build `.S` files, but `__ASSEMBLER__` is a pretty clear and good choice of name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to compile the header file. Try this:

```
# gcc -c common.S
```

without

```
#include <common.h>
```

in common.S

Comment: Im not sure that's an option. The idea to include the `#include` in the .S is not mine. Im reading OS code in the `arch/` section, and in there it includes the .h files.

Comment: Ahh OK.. leave the include and compile it without the header then -- you don't need to compile the header if its included.

Comment: `# gcc -c common.S  ` same output :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you review [Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html).

Comment: You ARE aware that you linked to a file:/// local to your machine, right?

Comment: @jonathon Reinhart   Oops, http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html